# Custom keyboard height doesn't change when device orientation changes

Tags: ios, iphone, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

Whenever I rotate device, my custom keyboard height always remains the same. I try to remove `Constraints` and add it again but no luck.
I have looked at lots of related question on Stack Overflow and on the iOS dev Forum as well but I still haven't a solution..

I read some where used app `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` but once I set the size using this code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self updateCustomHeight]; 
}


-(void)updateCustomHeight
{

    [self updateViewConstraints];
    CGFloat _expandedHeight = 250;

    NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0.0 constant:_expandedHeight];

    [self.view removeConstraint: _heightConstraint];
     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    if(isPortrait)
    {



        CGFloat _expandedHeight = 230;

        NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0.0 constant: _expandedHeight];

        [self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];

    }
    else
    {

        CGFloat _expandedHeight = 200;

        NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0.0 constant: _expandedHeight];

        [self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
    }

}
```

But when ever i load custom keyboard that setting first time setter frame display with landscape as well as portrait orientation.

**portrait**:

[image]

**Landscape:**

[image]

I calling that change size method when my orientation change delegate:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width < [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height){
        //Keyboard is in Portrait
        isPortrait=YES;

        [self LoadKeyboardview];
         [self updateCustomHeight];

    }
    else{

        isPortrait=NO;

        [self LoadKeyboardview];
         [self updateCustomHeight];

        //Keyboard is in Landscape
    }


}
```

**NOTE:**

For the keyboard layout i am using **XIB** and load nib as par device orientation that all working fine but that update of size in device orientation that wont working. please help me on this

Comment: Since you are writing an iOS 8 extension you should adopt the iOS 8 methods.  Rather than using `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` you should implement `viewWillTransitionToSize:` and implement size classes rather than hard-coding dimensions

Comment: well there is no issue with orientation that orientation and load nib working file issue is that change size is not working i already implementing size class.

Comment: I don't think that your approach to removing the height constraint is correct as you need to remove the actual constraint object instance, not just an equivalent constraint - you are removing a constraint that does not exist on the view, so it has no effect.  You should try and create your constraints relative to the containing view edge rather than specifying a height

Comment: the main thing is that that first time default oriantation size change code working and after that not working :(

Comment: Yes, because you aren't removing the initial height constraint.  You should store it as a property and then you can remove the actual constraint object rather than creating a new one.

Comment: can you please put as a answer with some example code or any other way so i can try to do as par your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the height constraint you need to keep it in a property so that you can subsequently remove it.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;

-(void)updateCustomHeight
{

    [self updateViewConstraints];
    CGFloat expandedHeight = 250;

    if (self.heightConstraint != nil) {
        [self.view removeConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    if(isPortrait)
    {
       expandedHeight = 230;
    }
    else
    {

       expandedHeight = 200;
    }

    self.heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0.0 constant: expandedHeight];
    [self.view addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i get same output nothing change @paulw11 :(

Comment: I don't think we have enough to go on here - for example, what does `updateViewConstraints` do?.  You should really use a single storyboard with appropriate constraints and size classes - then you won't need to do anything in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding two constraints one for portrait and one for landscape

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];

    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width < [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)
    {

        [self.view removeConstraint:_heightConstraintforLandscape];

    }
    else
    {
        [self.view removeConstraint:_heightConstraintforPortrait];
    }
}
```

I was able to solve the problem. The problem is due to the priority. Even if you set a different priority it's going the consider the initial, I don't know why it happens so.

Anyway setting up different constraints for landscape and portrait has helped me to keep a custom height. 
Hope it helps someone.